# adding several functions to one controller angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im trying to add another function to my controller but it keeps breaking the controller.

here is my code:

```js
.controller('ClimbController', [
 '$scope', '$stateParams', 'Climbs', function(
 $scope, $stateParams, Climbs) {

  var climb_id = $stateParams.climbId;
  var areaId = $stateParams.areaId;

  if (!isNaN(climb_id)) {
   climb_id = parseInt(climb_id);
  }

  if (!isNaN(areaId)) {
   areaId = parseInt(areaId);
  }

  $scope.selected_ = {};
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.details = true;
  // looping though all data and get particular product
  $scope.selectClimb = function(areas){
   areas.forEach(function(data) {
       if(data._id == climb_id){
        $scope.selected_ = data;
       }
   });
  }
  // get all posts // try some function to get a single produt from server
  $scope.getPosts = function(){
   Climbs.getPosts()
   .success(function (data) {
    // data = feed.json file

    var climbs = [];
    data.areas.map(function(area) {
     if (area._id === areaId) {
      climbs = area.climbs;
     }
    });
    $scope.selectClimb(climbs);
   })
   .error(function (error) {
    $scope.items = [];
   });
  }
  $scope.getPosts();
}
])
```

And I ned to add this to it:

```js
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('test-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
  //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.modal.remove();
  });
  // Execute action on hide modal
  $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
  // Execute action on remove modal
  $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
});
```

When I try to add this to the code it breaks it.  I nee to either add it as another function or whatever is needed to add it to the code.

Thanks so much

Comment: what breaks ?? you want to include `Myctrl` all functions into above controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to merge `'MyCtrl` functions into `ClimbController` then

```
.controller('ClimbController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Climbs','$ionicModal', function($scope, $stateParams, Climbs,$ionicModal) {

        var climb_id = $stateParams.climbId;
        var areaId = $stateParams.areaId;

        if (!isNaN(climb_id)) {
            climb_id = parseInt(climb_id);
        }

        if (!isNaN(areaId)) {
            areaId = parseInt(areaId);
        }

        $scope.selected_ = {};
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.details = true;
        // looping though all data and get particular product
        $scope.selectClimb = function(areas){
            areas.forEach(function(data) {
                if(data._id == climb_id){
                    $scope.selected_ = data;
                }
            });
        }
        // get all posts // try some function to get a single produt from server
        $scope.getPosts = function(){
            Climbs.getPosts()
            .success(function (data) {
                // data = feed.json file

                var climbs = [];
                data.areas.map(function(area) {
                    if (area._id === areaId) {
                        climbs = area.climbs;
                    }
                });
                $scope.selectClimb(climbs);
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.items = [];
            });
        }
        $scope.getPosts();


        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('test-modal.html', {
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
          }).then(function(modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
          });

          $scope.openModal = function() {
            $scope.modal.show();
          };
          $scope.closeModal = function() {
            $scope.modal.hide();
          };
          //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
          $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            $scope.modal.remove();
          });
          // Execute action on hide modal
          $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
            // Execute action
          });
          // Execute action on remove modal
          $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
            // Execute action
          });

}])
```

Comment: Thats it it was the } I had i the wrong spot that was mucking it up :)  and the }]) now closes.

Comment: @user1155141 sounds great that your problem have been solved up vote it